# "become known" vs. "come to be known"

Tags: phrase-usage, difference

Tell me please if following sentences have indentical meanings.

> The president **became known** as the most innovative president of all.
>
> The president **came to be known** as the most innovative president of all.

As a non-native speaker I cannot see the difference, and I would prefer to use the first one as it is less wordy.

Answer (score 2):

They do have the same meaning.

"became" is the past tense of "become", which is a verb that means "Begin to be".

"came to be":  "Came" is the past tense of come, which can [be defined as](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/come) "(with infinitive) Eventually reach a certain condition".